# Sitecore Lucene Index queue lagging behind in Prod server

Tags: sitecore

In our Sitecore (6.6) implementation we use Lucene indexing. In our PROD server, index bilding process is very slow. At the moment it has 5000+ entries to waiting in the index queue.

Queries I used (in master database),

```
select * from Properties (check the index last run time)

select * from History where created > 'last index updated time'
```

As a result of this delay, data gets created do not reflect their changes in the website. Also this queue keeps increasing. When the site takes offline, index building catch up after a while.

Its a heavy read intensive website.

We encountered CPU going high issues, but now they have been sorted. We thought index building was lagging because of the CPU high issue. But now the CPU is running around 30-40%. Still the lucene indexing queue increase rate is high.

How can I solve this issue? Please help.

Comment: What are you doing since there is more than 5000 items in the queue since last indexing time? Are you altering that many items in a short period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a database maintenance task, so that you regularly flush your History table. If you have sites that are index heavy, this table can grow excessively large. I think the default job cleans this table out with everything that is older than 30 days - you could set this much lower. Like 1 day, or a couple of days.

This article on SDN covers most of the standard maintenance tasks: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Database%20Maintenance.aspx

More general information about searching, indexing and performance here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc60-65-a4.pdf#search=%22clean%22

Comment: Oh, and finally you can decrease the Indexing.UpdateInterval setting - but I normally wouldn't recommend this. Running this one too frequently would not really solve the problem if your History table is running too big, rather it would make it worse

Comment: Finally, read Alex Shyba's article on indexing race conditions - you might need to consider this. http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/07/sync-up-sitecore-search-index-update.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a step back and ask the question as to why there is such a large number of entries being added to the history table to begin with, before looking at what configuration changes to Sitecore can be made.

You should trace through your code in your development environment based on each of the use cases for your implementation, to find all calls to the Sitecore API where an item is:

1. Added into the Sitecore Tree
2. Edited - the changing of any fields item including security, presentation, workflow, publishing restrictions, etc.
3. Duplicated
4. Deleted from the Sitecore Tree
5. Moved to a new location.
6. Has a new version is added
7. Has a version removed

As you are going through, make sure that all edit actions to an item are performed with in a single Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Editing.BeginEdit() and Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Editing.EndEdit() call whenever possible, so that the changes are performed as a single edit action instead of multiple. Every time Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Editing.EndEdit() is called, a new record will be inserted into the history table so unnecessary edits will only cause the history table size to increase.

If you are duplicating an item using the Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.CopyTo() method, remember that all versions of the item will be duplicated as well as the item's descendants. This means that the history table will have a record in it for every version of the item that was copied. If you only require the latest version and therefore removing older versions from the new item after it was created, again you should be aware that removing a version from an item will result in a record inserted into the history table for each version deleted.

If you have minimized all of the above actions to the bare minimum that is required to make the system functional, you should find that the Lucene Indexing will keep up-to-date pretty well without having to change Sitecore's default index configuration.